# MVC 4 connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

I've created an Internet application (MVC 4) in VS2012 and I'm trying to connect it to MySQL in a way so that I can have the OAuth functional.

I didn't manage to find anything helpful and I wonder if it's possible without some heavy workaround.

Comment: Are you using inbuilt OAuth?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what do you mean. It's a template that includes OAuth, so I suppose the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article

Implementaion of SingleMemmbershipProvider in MVC 4 for MySql and supports OAuth additionally.

http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/

Comment: thanks, I already gave it a try, but I don't intend buying LLBLGen, and without it's not likely that it's going to work.

Comment: LLBLGen has a free version now, and the blog post mentioned by Imran has been updated with a new sample download to leverage the free version of LLBLGen.

Answer (score 0):

`OAuth` with `MVC 4` template uses `SimpleMembershipProvider Class` which in turn uses MSSQL database. If you need to make it work for MySQL, then you need to override the methods in this class. You can do that as given at [this link](http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/) by Imran but according to me it is very heavy workaround to build your own overridden methods. Instead, drop the inbuilt OAUth and use custom one like [sharpOAuth](https://github.com/samo9789/sharpOAuth/wiki/How-To)

Comment: SharpDevelop is an IDE, isn't it? Can you please elaborate on how does it relate to the question? thanks!

Comment: @CloneXpert Sorry my mistake...i was using sharpDevelop so it was misspelled as sharpdevelop instead of sharpoauth..